# How to retrieve data from Firebase? dataSnapshot has the object but getValue() will return null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a planning poker app but I can't populate the recyclerview with the data from the database. My Firebase database looks like this:

[image: Database stucture]

The faulty code:

```
public void getAllData(){
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference.child("groups").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot iter : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Group group = iter.getValue(Group.class); 
                    for (Question question: group.getQuestionList()) {
                        RecyclerItem recyclerItem = new RecyclerItem(
                                question.getQuestionText(),
                                group.getStart_time(),
                                group.getEnd_time());
                        recyclerItemsList.add(recyclerItem);
                    }
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
    }
```

`Group group = iter.getValue(Group.class);` sets the `end_time` and `start_time`, but cannot set the `questions`.

Here is my Group.java file:

```
package com.example.planningpokerproject.Model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Group implements Parcelable {

    @PropertyName("start_time")
    private String start_time;

    @PropertyName("end_time")
    private String end_time;

    @PropertyName("questions")
    private ArrayList<Question> questions;


    public Group() {
    }

    public Group(String start_time, String end_time, ArrayList<Question> questionList){
        this.start_time = start_time;
        this.end_time = end_time;
        this.questions = questionList;
    }

    protected Group(Parcel in) {
        start_time = in.readString();
        end_time = in.readString();
        questions = in.createTypedArrayList(Question.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<Group> CREATOR = new Creator<Group>() {
        @Override
        public Group createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Group(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Group[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Group[size];
        }
    };

    public void setStart_time(String start_time) {

        this.start_time = start_time;
    }

    public void setEnd_time(String end_time) {
        this.end_time = end_time;
    }

    public void setQuestionList(ArrayList<Question> questionList) {
        this.questions = questionList;
    }

    public String getStart_time()
    {
        return this.start_time;
    }

    public String getEnd_time()
    {
        return this.end_time;
    }

    public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionList()
    {
        return this.questions;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("start_time", start_time);
        result.put("end_time", end_time);
        result.put("questions", questions);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(start_time);
        dest.writeString(end_time);
        dest.writeTypedList(questions);
    }
}
```

My question is how could I retrieve the `questions` with the `iter.getValue(Group.class)` or how should I do it?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the array of questions from each document in the database or are you having trouble populating your recycler view with data?

Comment: I want to retrieve the questions. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: It's just that the title is misleading, so please change it when you can. As far as the retrieval goes, you should be able to call `iter.get("questions)` and pass in the name of the field, here questions. That should return you the data from that field which you can use however you see fit

Comment: I tried it but ```iter``` doesn't have a get function. ```iter.getValue().get("questions")``` works in the watches but not in the code. It doesn't compile because neither ```iter``` nor ```iter.getValue()``` have a get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a reference to your collection and call the `get()` method on it to create a query for all the documents. You can then simply add an `OnCompleteListener` and access the documents retrieved via the `task : Task<QuerySnapshot>` as you see below. You should now be able to call the `get()` method on each document snapshot in order to get the values of your preferred field (in this case "questions"). The code is in kotlin but Android Studio should be able to turn it into a java file if you copy-paste.

```
val rootRef: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val collRef: CollectionReference = rootRef.collection("groups")
var questions = arrayListOf<String>()
collRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {task: Task<QuerySnapshot> ->
       if(task.isSuccessful) {
             Log.d(TAG,"Success")
             for(document:DocumentSnapshot in task.result!!) {
                     questions = document.get("questions")) // you may need to add some code here to actually get the questions field's values as an array
             }
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // notify the adapter about the new data
        }
}
```

Keep in mind that if your database is big, you should consider using data pagination to reqest the data in pieces(pages) instead of requesting it all at once.